# Why my Sql Script does not work?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am newbie to MySQL
I am trying to generate random data and put it into table 'data'

But SQL shell says that my sql code have syntax error
But I can't find why

```
DECLARE @counter smallint;
DECLARE @A BOOLEAN;
DECLARE @B BOOLEAN;
DECLARE @C int(4);
DECLARE @LABEL BOOLEAN;

SET @counter = 1;
WHILE @counter < 100
    BEGIN
       IF 0.5 > RAND()
            SET @A = TRUE;
        ELSE
            SET @A = FALSE;
        IF 0.5 > RAND()
            SET @B = TRUE;
        ELSE
            SET @B = FALSE;

        SET @C = RAND() * 10
        SET @LABEL = @A ^ @B OR @LABEL > 5

        INSERT INTO data (A,B,C,LABEL) VALUES (@A,@B,@C,@LABEL)
        @count = @count +1
    END
```

It says that I have syntax problem
from declaring variables

can you help me?

Comment: Show the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is missing some syntax words:

- `IF`... `THEN`  ... `ELSE`  ... `END IF`;
- `WHILE` ... `DO` ... `END WHILE`;

Is important understand that user variables are written as **@var_name**, so user-defined variables are session-specific. That is, a user variable defined by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients. All variables for a given client session are automatically freed when that client exits. In this case, I think that is not necessary.

`SET`, either `=` or `:=` can be used as the assignment operator.

Try this:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter smallint;
    DECLARE A BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE B BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE C int(4);
    DECLARE LABEL BOOLEAN;

    SET counter = 1;
    WHILE counter < 100 DO
        IF 0.5 > RAND() THEN
            SET A = TRUE;
        ELSE
            SET A = FALSE;
        END IF;

        IF 0.5 > RAND() THEN
            SET B = TRUE;
        ELSE
            SET B = FALSE;
        END IF;

        SET C = RAND() * 10;

        IF A ^ B OR LABEL > 5 THEN
            SET LABEL = TRUE;
        ELSE
            SET LABEL = FALSE;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO data (A,B,C,LABEL) VALUES (A,B,C,LABEL);
        SET counter = counter +1;
    END WHILE;
END//
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
DECLARE @counter smallint,
DECLARE @A BOOLEAN,
DECLARE @B BOOLEAN,
DECLARE @C int(4),
DECLARE @LABEL BOOLEAN;
```